# Do anyone know if Veracrypt works with any Deep Freeze alternatives?

Tags: encryption, freeze

Does anyone know if veracrypt encryption would work with Deep freeze or any alternatives? Disk encryption with any software that can remove viruses or protect against virus in windows more easy.

https://alternativeto.net/software/deep-freeze/?license=free

Veracryt:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeraCrypt

Thanks allot.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what setup you want to do.

A working setup can be:

- Partition and Format your drives the way you want it.
- Install VeraCrypt, and mount all your encrypted containers or partitions.
  While the containers are mounted, install Deep Freeze Alternate with the option to only freeze drive C:.

Installing Deep Freeze Alternate last it should see all the partitions and mounted drives. Otherwise, it may reset to frozen status on any other drives it doesn't see initially.

So in conclusion, DF your C: and let the other partitions (like D: with has encrypted volumes and the mounted volumes themselves) untouched.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems you are thinking of containers, and i am looking to encrypt the whole system. But i am not sure this kind of software would work with that. Deep freeze might work. I have not tried.

Comment: It's quite similar. Just exclude the partitions you don't want frozen.